# <> hangs on STDIN after reading non-empty @ARGV

Tags: perl

The code below is the skeleton of a perl program to process some files with structured text. The program works as expected if the input is provided via STDIN:

```
./process_files.pl < some_file
```

But it hangs if the file to be processed is a command line argument:

```
./process_files.pl some_file
```

Running this under strace showed that after reading the file, the program is stuck on `read(0, ...)`.  And sure enough, typing Ctrl-D at the terminal unsticks the program and it then runs to completion.

Why is perl waiting on STDIN after reading from a non-empty @ARGV?

The perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub meta
{
    while ( <> )
    {
        return if m!</META>!;
        # process metadata line
    }
}

sub data
{
    while ( <> )
    {
        return if m!</DATA>!;
        # process data line
    }
}

while ( <> )
{
    meta if m!<META>!;
    data if m!<DATA>!;
}

# post processing here

exit 0;
```

ADDENDUM: the lines of the text file being processed have this pattern:

```
lines (ignored)
<META>
meta data lines (processed)
</META>
lines (ignored)
<DATA>
data lines (processed)
</DATA>
optional lines (ignored)
```

Comment: It's very dangerous to use nested calls to while-readline without a lexical. It assigns globally to `$_` without localizing it, so your calls to `meta` and `data` will clobber whatever is currently there. Try changing all your loops to assign to lexicals: `while (my $line = <>) { $line =~ m!...! }` It's also better to use [<<>>](https://perldoc.pl/perl5220delta#New-double-diamond-operator) instead of `<>` if you're on a new enough Perl (5.22+)

Comment: As it happens, the same bizarre behavior occurs even with scoped lexicals.  [The program is single purpose (load lines into custom structures and then produce post-processed output) so leveraging the global $_ is okay here.]

Comment: Perl 5.16.3 on Red Hat Maipo (Enterprise Linux 7.3).  The file names are quite normal too, no funny characters or the like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you kept read from `ARGV` after it returned EOF.

Reading from `ARGV` removes the entries from `@ARGV` as it opens them, so `@ARGV` was empty the second go around, causing the read to read from STDIN.

Your program boils down to the following:

```
print "\@ARGV: @ARGV\n";     # Outputs: @ARGV: file.txt
while (<>) { }               # Reads from file.txt.
print "\@ARGV: @ARGV\n";     # Outputs: @ARGV:
while (<>) { }               # Reads from STDIN.
```

---

By the way, you should never expect a file handle that returned EOF to keep returning EOF. This is not always the case. For example, it's not the case for handles to terminals on POSIX systems.

Comment: Sorry, you lost me. What "second go around"?  The `while ( <> )` loop should end when @ARGV is exhausted.  There is no second while-loop after that.

Comment: You have not two, but three... You're getting into a situation where the loop in `meta` or `data` continues until EOF, after which you call `<>`  in the main program.

Comment: Solution: Use a proper HTML? XML? parser instead of this shoddy thing.

Comment: These are not properly tagged files, so there is no off-the-shelf parser. Further, the nested while loops do not run to EOF: they specifically exit when a special line is encountered (return if...).

Comment: One if them isn't. You're getting into a situation where the loop in `meta` or `data` continues until EOF, after which you call `<>`  in the main program.

Comment: Okay, that's a logical explanation, thank you. I'll scrutinize the code again.